# How to split value from string and get in variables?

Tags: php

I tried to split value from string. How to do it in php?

```
$data = "1-2021, 2-2018, 3-2022";
Output should be,
var1= "1,2,3"
var2 = "2018,2022,2022"
```

Comment: Please show us your best attempt (code) and share what does not work as expected. Read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: The first thing to try is to read the PHP Manual. Specifically the [PHP String Functions page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) Where lots of useful functions are documented that help with string manipuation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split your items from string you need to use [Explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function of php.
After splitting If you want to merge them back you need to use [Implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function of it.

So basicly from what you give you need to split your string first, then create 2 different arrays and add your items into it, lastly merge them back like this:

```
/*----- Define 2 arrays as holders ------*/
    $arr1 = array();
    $arr2 = array();

/*----- Get data and explode it ------*/
    $data = "1-2021, 2-2018, 3-2022";
    $data_exploded = explode(', ', $data);

/*----- Iterate over each item and explode them too ------*/
    foreach($data_exploded as $item){
        
        /*----- Explode here  ------*/
            $item_arr = explode('-', $item);

        /*----- Add sub items into holders ------*/
            array_push($arr1, $item_arr[0]);
            array_push($arr2, $item_arr[1]);

    }

/*----- Finally Implode your holders ------*/
    $var1 = implode(',', $arr1); // Output = "1,2,3"
    $var2 = implode(',', $arr2); // Output = "2018,2022,2022"
```

For further examination please check the links above.